# Can not dispaly Json data in to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to use a local JSON file into HTML using JavaScript.
I can load the data from JSON into console, but not into HTML page.
can somebody have a look at my code and tell me where is my mistake please?

here is my code:

```
const sejoursData = new XMLHttpRequest();
sejoursData.open('GET', './data.json');

sejoursData.onload = function()
{

console.log(sejoursData.responseText);

var loadData = JSON.parse(sejoursData.responseText);

function sejourTemplate(sejours){

  return `
  <div class="sejour">
  <img class="sejour-photo" src="${sejours.imageUrl}">
  <h2 class="sejour-titre">${sejoursData.titre}</h2>
  <span class="font">${sejours.description}</span>

  <h4 class="font">${sejours.theme}</h4>
  <P class="font">${sejours.dateDebut}</P>
  <P class="font">${sejours.dateFin}</P>
  <P class="font">${sejours.prix}</P>
  <P class="font">${sejours.promotion}</h4><br>
  <input type="button" value="Favorit" class="btn-primary" id="btn">
  </div>
  `
};

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = `

<h1 class="app-title">Resultas pour le Sejours ( ${sejoursData.length} )</h1>
${sejoursData.map(sejourTemplate).join('')}
`
};
sejoursData.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you provided the results of `console.log(sejoursData.responseText);`, that would be helpful.
2. Here

```
<h1 class="app-title">Resultas pour le Sejours ( ${sejoursData.length} )</h1>
${sejoursData.map(sejourTemplate).join('')}
```

it's `loadData` that you should be using, not `sejoursData`. `loadData` is the one parsed into an object.

```
<h1 class="app-title">Resultats pour le Sejours ( ${loadData.length} )</h1>
${loadData.map(sejourTemplate).join('')}
```

Comment: have a nice day